# Facebook Messenger Approval Policy

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm in the process of creating a Facebook Messenger chatbot using Chatfuel.

It is designed to collect all the information about a certain musical band together in one place.  It allows users to play the bands music via links to spotify, and to buy them through amazon, using an affiliate link. See a biography, link off to merchandise, watch youtube videos etc....

I've just watched a video on the review process and it tells me.... (Udemy course)

```
No marketing or promotional messages.
No advertising, sale or product announcements.
No Brand advertising, branded content.
No Newsletters or announcements
No Upselling or cross selling of products or services
No Referral program or incentive promotions
```

Yet on the Facebook Messenger page it tells me

```
Raise Awareness
Get your business, product or service in front of more people.

Acquire Customers
Generate more leads and turn your conversations into conversions.

Enable Transactions
Incorporate account linking and purchase flows to enable more transactions.
```

Robbie Williams and Aerosmith have both just released chatbots, which effective promote and sell their album, tour and merchendise by sending the user to various web pages, they don't actually do it in the chatbot.

My problem is that I cannot actually find this information on the Facebook site. I've looked through all the documentation and review policies and there is nothing about these restrictions.

I am wondering if this video is referring to unsolicited messages (broadcasting) sent by the chatbot rather than user button clicking?

Can anyone point me in the right direction to find the relevant docs? I feel I may be wasting my time developing this and need some official confirmation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at [official policy page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/policy-overview), "Comparison of Messaging Types" paragraph is a good summary. Basically there are two tipes of messaging that your bot can make:

- Standard Messaging (inside 24 hours window from last user interaction with bot)
- Subscription Messaging and Customer Matching (allows messaging outside 24 hours window)

Standard messaging allows all use cases including promotional material. I think that Udemy video might be outdated, hence this quote:

> The restriction on promotional content has been removed for standard messaging.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. These are the pages I was reading but it says nothing about content. So its more about how the message is triggered than the content. If my bot only responds instantly, I can include the links, including the affiliate links.